# Frameworks are missing in Unity generated Xcode project

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

Some of the frameworks are missing when I generate Xcode project through Unity. What would be the reason? How can I solve this?

I mean manually I have added them in Build Phases to fix the error, but why are they missing?

Comment: Which frameworks? Are you adding native code to the project?

Comment: @ThomasW I am using MapKit in my application. I have imported the framework into my objective-c file, but when I generate the Xcode project through Unity MapKit framework is missing in the project.

Answer (score 0):

They're missing because they are required when you use those APIs.

If you're coming from a language like Java this might seem strange, but with Objective-C (which is ultimately C) you need to let the compiler know where the APIs come from beyond just the header file import.

Unfortunately, Unity doesn't provide any support for specifying additional frameworks for your Xcode project to link to. However, if you can you should generate and modify your Xcode project once and then subsequently always have Unity update rather than override the project.